# Need to put different color for same bar in vistime based on percentage

Tags: r

I need different color based on percentage. For example for the same bar, I need 60 % in red and other 40 % of the same bar to be blue.

```
pres <- data.frame(Position = rep(c("President", "Vice"), each = 3),
                       Name = c("Washington", rep(c("Adams", "Jefferson"), 2), "Burr"),
                       start = c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", "1801-02-03"),
                       end = c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", "1809-02-03"),
                       color = c('#cbb69d', '#603913', '#c69c6e'),
                       fontcolor = c("black", "white", "black"))
    vistime::vistime(pres, events="Position", groups="Name", title="Presidents of the USA")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `color` column in your data frame. You can just change this to change the colors of the bars:

```r
 pres <- data.frame(Position = rep(c("President", "Vice"), each = 3),
                       Name = c("Washington", rep(c("Adams", "Jefferson"), 2), "Burr"),
                       start = c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", "1801-02-03"),
                       end = c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", "1809-02-03"),
                       color = c('red', 'blue', 'green'), # Changed this line
                       fontcolor = c("black", "white", "black"))


vistime::vistime(
    pres, 
    events="Position", 
    groups="Name", 
    title="Presidents of the USA"
)
```

[image]